# Share instance of complex object across activities in different submodules

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am working on a refactoring effort to restructure an existing android mobile app into submodules, the aim of the refactoring is to have the app divided into a core section which contains a main submodule and an interfaces submodule and a features section with submodules for each feature offered by the app. The app should have the structure shown below

[image]

The new structure of the app however dictates that certain instances of complex objects created in the main module must be shared with all the feature modules(the activities and viewmodels in the module) and this is where the problem lies. It is basically the often encountered problem of passing data between activities but with a twist, the instance to be passed is a really complex object which means it can't be serialized and deserilized and thus can't be passed using intents. I can't use shared preferences or db because of the serializtion issue too. I have considered using a dependency injection framework like Dagger but I don't know how to make that work with already existing instances of objects. Any advise on how to make this work? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could consider implementing  `Parcelable` interface to enable marshalling and unmarshalling by the Android system.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable

Comment: that won't work. The object is to complex to be serialized.

Comment: Do you have to communicate each part of the object?